# ffmpeg output files differ

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ogg, fluent-ffmpeg

The following code outputs differing files. Why?

I used both the `diff` command and `cmp` which says they start to differ at byte 15. I also tried changing the argument to `toFormat()` from 'ogg' to 'mp3'. Same results.

```
ffmpeg( './original/test.mp3' )
    .toFormat( 'ogg' )
    .on( 'error', function(error, stdout, stderr)
    {
        console.log( 'Cannot process file: \n' + error );
    })
    .output( './tmp_a/' + filename )
    .output( './tmp_b/' + filename )
    .run();
```

I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong or if this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OGG format muxer writes a unique serial number or ID tag. Add `-flags +bitexact` to set it to zero.

Comment: Oh okay so ffmpeg just reruns the algorithm for each output() call.
I tried adding `inputOptions( '-flags +bitexact' )` just before `toFormat()`, but the files still differed. Your explanation still makes sense though.

Comment: I don't know node.js syntax, but it's an output option, not input.

Comment: If you want to encode it once and save in multiple files, you have to use the tee muxer.